# Socket.io on CloudFront (S3) client won't send certificate to Node.js server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, certificate, amazon-cloudfront

We're using the simplest possible implementation of a socket.io client and server to eliminate any variables regarding the cause of this problem. The socket.io client is in JavaScript on AWS CloudFront using a custom domain and the server is on node (nginx). We are getting a secure connection and everything is working as expected except that CloudFront is refusing to pass the certificate. Here is what we get from socket.io regarding the connection:

```
accept: '*/*',
     origin: 'https://cdn.ourdomain.com',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36',
     'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
     'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
     referer: 'https://cdn.ourdomain.com/ourapp.iframe.html',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
     cookie: '_ga=GA1.2.245674994.1569802743; __zlcmid=uXiZmTTN1V8j16; _gcl_au=1.1.312077107.1570950743; _gid=GA1.2.851127118.1572308315; __gads=ID=a55ec67b74740d6a:T=1572647855:S=ALNI_MYuzmlVp2hvDIbUS5LuYBD4kYKHlA; io=gkqtOKgx38ddpH6dAAAA; _gat=1' },
  time: 'Sat Nov 02 2019 07:41:25 GMT+0000 (UTC)',
  address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
  xdomain: true,
  secure: true,
  issued: 1572680485150,
  url: '/ourapp-secure-connection/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Muh3xpR',
  query: { EIO: '3', transport: 'polling', t: 'Muh3xpR' } }
Client connected [id=LKTQbOl3_DdAJeH5AAAB, cert={}]
```

Nothing we've tried has returned anything other than cert={}. I've seen some references in the AWS documentation about CloudFront dropping custom certificate requests. Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

*"CloudFront is refusing to pass the certificate"* isn't an entirely accurate description of what is happening.  Client certificates can't be "passed" through an HTTP reverse-proxy like CloudFront -- it's impossible, by design, because that would be the equivalent of a man-in-the-middle attack.  (This is also true of other reverse proxies, like HAProxy in HTTP mode and Amazon Application Load Balancer.)

You can't split open a TLS connection in the middle, by design.  It may appear that this is what CloudFront does, but it isn't.  Instead, CloudFront is decrypting the payload from the server (or client) and re-encrypting it for transmission to the client (or server)... and it can do this only because there are two separate TLS sessions, one from browser to CloudFront and the other from CloudFront to the server -- CloudFront ties the decrypted payload pipes together, internally.